# SetNeedsDisplay not working

Tags: ios, setneedsdisplay

I saw many threads related to this issue, but none addresses my case (I think).

My case should be simple, I have a Custom `UIView` in my controller, from my controller, I use the [`self.myView setNeedsDisplay`] and it works perfectly.

I'm having problems when Im trying to call this from inside of the `UIView` itself...I have a notification being sent from another class, and it is being received by my View (this works) with the information it passes, I update internal properties of this view and than I'm calling the [self `setNeedsDisplay`] wishing to have my screen updated with the new states, but nothing is happening, I used a `NSLOG` inside my `drawRec` method, and it is not being called at this time, it is only called when my controller class call the `setNeedsDisplay`, and when that happens, the update that should have happened before is showed on screen... I don't know why its not updating before...

Here are some code:

My controller asking for update: (works OK!)

```
- (void)addNodeToNetwork:(DTINode *)node
{
[self.myNetwork addNodeInTheNetwork:node];
self.gridView.nodesToDraw = [self.myNetwork.nodesInNetwork copy];

CGRect tempRec = CGRectMake(node.nodePosition.x, node.nodePosition.y node.nodePosition.x, node.nodePosition.y);
NSValue *rectObj = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:tempRec]; //transforma o cgrect num objeto

[self.gridView.fatherNodes setValue:rectObj forKey:node.nodeName];
[self.gridView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

My notification method trying to update my drawing: (Not Working ! )

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
DTINode *notificationNode = [userInfo objectForKey:@"myNode"];
NSLog(@"Im Here!");
for (DTINode *node in self.nodesToDraw)
{
    NSLog(@"Here too");

    if(node.nodeName == notificationNode.fatherNode)
    {
        CGRect temp = CGRectMake(notificationNode.nodePosition.x, notificationNode.nodePosition.y, node.nodePosition.x, node.nodePosition.y);
        NSValue *tempObj = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:temp];
        [self.fatherNodes setObject:tempObj forKey:notificationNode.nodeName];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        NSLog(@"Should REDRAW NOW!"); // It print this but no drawing is made!
    }
}
}
```

I'm not pasting my `drawRect` here because it works, the problem is that is is not being called from inside my `UIView setNeedsDisplay`!

Anyone have any idea why this is not working????

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After alot of testing, I saw something related to threads and the fact setNeedsDisplay should only be called in the mainThread...besides I never started a separeted thread in this classes, the class that raised the Notification was in a secondary thread...and aparently this was causing the issue...

to Solve it I just forced setNeedsDisplay to be called in the main thread..

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setNeedsDisplay];  
});
```

Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: It does work in iOS 9.3.1 for me. The issue was I was on another thread just like the solution says.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to use it is:

```
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Although I always have problems to get that working :(